# A time period before a another time period

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm trying to phrase something like this:

> ...an event that occurred immediately before his injury

However, `immediately` isn't the word I want.  I looking for something something that implies that it was a little more in the past than immediately, but not too far.  If I weren't already referencing a past event I'd say something like

> ...an event that occurred *recently*.

But,

> ...an event that occurred recently before his injury.

doesn't sound correct to me.

What's the word I'm looking for?

Comment: ...an event that occurred  [a while][a short while][not long][a little][some time] before his injury

Comment: How about *...an event which occurred only just before his recent injury* ?.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Perfect!  I don't know why I was fixated on using a single word.  Brain fart I guess.

Comment: @WS2: also good.  Post as answers and I'll upvote.  Sorry I only have one "accepted" to give :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

...an event that occurred [a while][a short while][not long][a little][some time] before his injury –

Comment: or [shortly] before

Comment: or "right before".

Comment: or "just before"

Comment: Additionally, consider using "that had occurred".

Answer (score 1):

How about ...***an event which occurred only just before his recent injury*** ?